# How to use IF statement that provided by DoctrineExtensions

Tags: if-statement, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm playing with [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) but can not manage it. After register DoctrineExtensions, I have following line of DQL with Zend Framework:

```
$qb->having(new IfElse("A.type = 0", new FindInSet(1, new GroupConcat('B.id', ',')) >0 , '1') );
```

But get this error msg:

> Exception information:
>
> Message: Expression of type 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\IfElse'
>   not allowed in this context.*

Could you help me to point out what incorrect in my command or any document on how to use DoctrineExtensions?

UPDATED:

I've found a the way to implement custom function by :
I have given it a litle try by adding this line to boostrap:

```
$config->addCustomStringFunction('IF', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\IfElse');
```

And use it in DQL as:

```
$qb->having("IF( A.type = 0, S.status = 0, S.status = 1 )");
```

But get this error:

Message: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 152: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_COMMA, got '='

Maybe I'm wrong in syntax?

Comment: I'm back late, and leave comment here for one who facing same problem. It's a bit more complex than original question but that what I have :
$qb->having("IF (" . $qb->expr()->neq('S.userId', $arrCondition['current_user']) . ",
      IF (
      FIND_IN_SET(" . $arrCondition['current_user'] . ",
      IF ( i.type > 1 , '',IF (i.type = 0, GROUP_CONCAT(i.receiver), GROUP_CONCAT(i.createdBy) ))
    ) >= 0,
      i.status,
      0
    ), 1 ) = 1"
                );

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$qb->having("S.status = IF( A.type = 0, 0, 1 )");
```